# Use field choices from model in another app

Tags: django

I'm trying to set the `choices` property of a model field as the static property from another model (in another app). Code explains it better:

```
# school.models
class Group(models.Model):
    TYPES = (
        (1, 'Some type'),
        (2, 'Some other type'),
    )
```

And:

```
# student.models
from school.models import Group   # circular import

class StudentHistory(models.Model):
    group_type = models.IntegerField(choices=Group.TYPES)
```

So this way, I'm getting a circular import. Also tried `get_model('school', 'Group')`, but apparently the appcache isn't loaded yet at that point, so that returns `None`.

Comment: importing models as `from school import models` and accessing `models.Group.TYPES` raises exception too?

Comment: Doesn't compile. `ImportError: cannot import name models`

Comment: what about lazy evaluation: `from django.utils.functional import lazy
... choices=lazy(  lambda: ( get_model('school', 'Group'), tuple )  )`

Comment: Why don't you define the Choice List outside the Model? import then the choices to each model file and use that, since you want to share the logic, remove the bond of it to a specific Model.

Comment: @petkostas because of the semantic. The `TYPES` property is the group type, so it would make sense for it to be part of the `Group` model. I will try @danihp's solution and if that doesn't work, I will pull it out of the model and live with it.

Comment: Leave it as a separate entity under the group app `project/groupapp/groups.py` there is no need to move it outside the app, just move it outside the model if this creates problems :)